# FireFoxDriver cant find e;ements using Jquery Selectors

Tags: jquery, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver, selenide

When i run **chrome driver all is ok**, but firefox always throws

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.jQuery: "$( [data-auto-sub-section-title='Onset']:eq(0) .vmr-select-control)"

calling FF driver:

```
public WebDriver getStandaloneFF() {
    FirefoxDriverManager.getInstance(FirefoxDriver.class).setup();
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
    return driver;
}
```

Is there any known issues with firefox driver+jquery selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in

```
@Override
public List<WebElement> findElements(SearchContext context) {
    WebDriver driver = getWebDriverFromSearchContext(context);

    if (!isJQueryInThisPage(driver)) {
        try {
            injectJQuery(driver);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return new ByJavaScript("return $(\"" + query + "\")").findElements(context);
}
```

i've changed

```
 return new ByJavaScript("return $(\"" + query + "\")").findElements(context);
```

to

```
return new ByJavaScript("return $(\"" + query + "\")toArray()").findElements(context);
```

and problem was resolved